# ExecutionException - SocketTimeoutException while trying to call 10 different rest services asynchronously with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, node.js, spring, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a Java 8 Application with Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE. From this application I send requests to 10 different Rest services asynchronously.

UPDATE: These 10 different Rest services are 10 different endpoints on a monolitic application.

Code works fine but sometimes requests hang and throws SocketTimeoutException. If I put some timeout on RestTemplate object, it throws the exception after that specific timeout. But if I do not put a timeout, requests hang and after a while it throws the same exception. Service that my application calls is written with Node.js and error from that application is below:

```
ERROR CATCHED:  ClientError [BadRequestError]: request aborted
at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:492:9)
message: 'request aborted',
type: 'request.aborted'
```

As far as I have read about this case, this error occurred because of request being cancelled before that Node.js application reads the request. For example when you click SEND button from Postman and instantly click Cancel button. But when I send requests synchronously one after another nothing goes wrong but the time elapsed. I do not want to call these services synchronously for my performance issues.

Exception on Java side is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "SOMEURL":Read time out after 1000 millis; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read time out after 1000 millis
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:330)
at tr.com.ingbank.service.impl.IntentServiceImpl.getIntentResponse(IntentServiceImpl.java:231)
at tr.com.ingbank.service.impl.IntentServiceImpl.access$000(IntentServiceImpl.java:51)
at tr.com.ingbank.service.impl.IntentServiceImpl$1.get(IntentServiceImpl.java:105)
at tr.com.ingbank.service.impl.IntentServiceImpl$1.get(IntentServiceImpl.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read time out after 1000 millis
at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOInputStream.readInternal(NIOSocketMuxer.java:855)
at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOInputStream.read(NIOSocketMuxer.java:788)
at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOInputStream.read(NIOSocketMuxer.java:771)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:310)
at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:232)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:549)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:639)
at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1445)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:542)
... 8 more
```

My async REST call code is below:

```
CompletableFuture<IntentResponse> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<IntentResponse>() {

    @Override
    public IntentResponse get() {

        System.out.println("Calling service asynchronously with botName=" + finalBotName);
        try {
            return getIntentResponse(finalIntentRequest, finalBotName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // insert error log
            return new IntentResponse();
        }

    }

});

futures.add(future);
```

This code block is inside a for loop and this is how all requests are prepared. After all requests are ready I call the *get()* method and this runs all rest calls and *allOf()* method allows my application to wait for all responses.

```
CompletableFuture<IntentResponse>[] responseFuturesArray = (CompletableFuture<IntentResponse>[]) new CompletableFuture[futures.size()];
futures.toArray(responseFuturesArray);

CompletableFuture<Void> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(responseFuturesArray);

result.get();

for(CompletableFuture<IntentResponse> future : futures){

    intentResponses.add(future.get());

}
```

The method which is called asynchronously is a simple REST call with RestTemplate class from Springframework. In case something is wrong I share this method as well:

```
private IntentResponse getIntentResponse(IntentRequest intentRequest, String botName) throws Exception {

    String url = appConfigService.getAppConfigValueByType(AppConstants.INTERNAL_INTENT_ENGINE_URL);
    String token = appConfigService.getAppConfigValueByType(botName);
    url = url + botName;
    String sessionIdWithBotName = intentRequest.getUserId();
    String sessionId = sessionIdWithBotName.split("_").length > 1 ? sessionIdWithBotName.split("_")[1] : sessionIdWithBotName;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.add("Cbot-Token", token);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();


    HttpEntity<IntentRequest> request = new HttpEntity<IntentRequest>(intentRequest, headers);
    IntentResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, IntentResponse.class);
    response.setBotName(botName);

    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    // insert log

    return response;
}
```

I have been dealing with this problem for 2 weeks and there is nothing I haven't tried. I tried to write the method where it sends the request with HttpUrlConnection, ExecutorService - newCachedThreadPool, newFixedThreadPool etc. and I know their differences but all of them has the same error and there is no pattern on these errors (Not related to the request, not related to time or time intervals between requests..). Either all requests are sent successfully and recieved response successfully, or all of them hangs, timeouts or whatever it is called. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn't lie with the Node.js service(s)?

Comment: I am not sure, to be honest I don't think so. It seems that the request never arrives Node.js application or it arrives but connection is cut when Node.js application tries to read the request. Besides that, if I send requests one by one nothing goes wrong. This led me thinking the problem is related to weblogic server and its way of controling threads. But I have found nothing useful lately.

Comment: Why r u looping futures again and invoking intentResponses.add(future.get());. This makes problem for you. Try this this code instead of that for-loop CompletableFuture<List<IntentResponse>> res = futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: remove this code:CompletableFuture<IntentResponse>[] responseFuturesArray = (CompletableFuture<IntentResponse>[]) new CompletableFuture[futures.size()];
futures.toArray(responseFuturesArray);

CompletableFuture<Void> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(responseFuturesArray);

result.get();

for(CompletableFuture<IntentResponse> future : futures){

    intentResponses.add(future.get());

}

Comment: I will try your first recommendation, but for the second one; if i remove that piece of code will it wait for all to complete? I know that allOf() method makes it wait for all to complete and i have to call get() method in order to trigger them all. Is this wrong?

Comment: Btw, I have tried them all. Still same error..

Comment: both are single recommendation only. CompletableFuture<List<IntentResponse>> res = futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()); add this code instead of using (CompletableFuture<IntentResponse>[]) new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]; futures.toArray(responseFuturesArray); CompletableFuture<Void> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(responseFuturesArray); result.get(); for(CompletableFuture<IntentResponse> future : futures){ intentResponses.add(future.get()); }

Comment: allOf() wont return you anything. refer https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/  and try to understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204099/discussion-between-nalla-srinivas-and-nope).